# How to use sus2/sus4/add9 in minor key to stay within the key

Tags: chords, harmony, scales, composition

I understand how to use sus2/sus4 and add9 inn major to keep all notes within the chosen major scale, but how can I use the same chords in a minor key and still stay in key?

Comment: Surely the same way. With su2/4 there's no clue as to major or minor, so what's the difference? With add9, the maj./min. is implicit..

Comment: Just to get an idea, could you explain your current understanding? I'm about 92% certain that everyone around here has a different understanding or guess about the question. What are you trying to do, and what kind of problems are you having in a minor key? What do you mean by "in key"?

Comment: By 'in key' i mean for C major/A minor I ONLY want to hear the notes C, D, E, F, G, A, B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First keep in mind that minor keys actually use three different scales for melodic and harmonic purposes, the natural, harmonic and melodic minor scales. Let’s just look at the diatonic chords of only the C natural minor scale. Keep in mind that using a sus2 or sus4 chord takes away the 3rd, the chord tone that makes a chord either major or minor:

The i: Cm, Csus2, Csus4, Cm(add 9)

The iio: Do (sus 2,4 and add 9 are not possible unless you use melodic minor)

The III: Eb, Ebsus2, Ebsus4, Eb(add 9)

The iv: Fm, Fsus2, Fsus4, Fm(add 9)

The v: Gm, (sus 2 and add 9 are not possible unless you use melodic minor) Gsus4,

The VI: Ab, Absus2, Ab(add 9) (sus4 would contain Db, not D natural)

The VII: Bb, Bbsus2, Bbsus4, Bb(add 9)

This is not taking into account all the other options available by using the harmonic or melodic minor scales. I would also like to add that there is no need to stay “in key” when composing unless you are challenging yourself to do so for whatever reason you might have.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is the most useful for my use case.

Comment: I don’t have enough reputation to comment on an answer, but beware that there is an issue in your favored answer. The VI cannot have sus4 and stay in the minor key because the 4 (relative to the VI) is a semitone above the root. The sus2 is ok on the VI though because the 2 (relative to the VI) is the VII of the key.

Comment: @MightyMorphism I answered this ages ago but hey, good catch! I will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Jazz chord symbols are not relative to a key.

The are relative to a major dominant thirteenth chord. All interval numbers and modifiers work from that base chord: triads are major, sevenths are minor, ninths major, elevenths perfect, thirteenths major. Modifiers work from those defaults.

So, `G7` is a `G` root, major triad, and minor seventh.

But, `Gmin7♭5` get the modifiers `min` and `♭5` as changes to the defaults.

Sorry, for that tedious explanation, but it's important, because the main part of your question about suspensions is that they work the same in major and minor keys. Suspensions are dissonances over a chord root which traditionally get resolved to consonances. That's the same in major and minor keys.

The thing that changes with jazz chord symbols and major and minor keys is the *specific quality of all intervals* in chord symbols. It isn't limited to just the intervals of suspensions.

You can now look at your list...

> sus2/sus4 and add9

...and first say...

- `sus2` is a major second above the root
- `sus4` is a perfect fourth above the root
- `add9` is a major ninth above the root

Now you just need to know where those are not the diatonic intervals in minor. I will just work with a minor key signature on not bother with the variable sixth and seventh scale degrees in minor...

- seconds are minor between `^2/^3` and `^5/^6`, a suspended second on a `iio` or `V`
- fourths are augmented between `^6/^2`, a suspended fourth on a `♭VI`
- ninths are just an octave added to seconds so the minor ninths are the same as the minor seconds between `^2/^3` and `^5/^6`, a suspended second on a `iio` or `V`

If a chord deals with those intervals you need to add a flat to it to show the change that makes it diatonic in minor. You do this regardless whether the interval is a chord tone or a suspension tone.

To show how both chord tone intervals *and* suspension intervals change to fit a major or minor key tonality here are two examples, major first, then minor...

[image]

[image]

...I put courtesy accidentals in parenthesis to show any interval modified from the default dominant thirteenth chord. Those correspond to the jazz chord modifiers `m` for minor triads, `sus#4`, `Δ7`, `♭5`, and `♭9`.

It's tedious, but if you really want major or minor key tonality, you need to spell/label intervals correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Chords are defined independently of the key of the surrounding music. `C` = `CEG` even if the piece itself is in, say, `E major`.

The definitions of the OP chords are:

- Sus2 = root - M2 - P5
- Sus4 = root - P4 - P5
- Add9 = root - third - fifth - M9

Suppose we're in `C major` `Csus2` = `CDG`. All notes are diatonic to `C major`. This is also true in `C minor`.

But consider the chord `Dsus2`: `DEA`. In `C major`, this chord is again diatonic, but not in `C minor`. To remain diatonic in `C minor`, the chord would be either `Dsus[b2][b5]` or `Dsus[b2]`, depending on whether the context has the flat or raised sixth (minor keys allow for both, as well as both flat and raised seventh).

Similar alterations can be made to other chords. For example:

1. an `Fsus4` (`FBbC`) is not diatonic to `C major`. For a diatonic version in `C major`, the chord would be altered to `Fsus[#4]`.
2. in `C minor`, change `Dadd9` to `Dadd[b9]` in order to include `Eb` in the chord instead of `E`.

Comment: 'Chords are defined independently of the key of the surrounding music' - then later you quote chord names diatonically. I'm confused.

Comment: @Tim Can you point out one of the chords you have in mind?

Comment: DEA - Dsus2. becomes Dsusb2 in Cm. So now is DEbA - sounding strange!

Comment: Yeah 9th's are not considered diatonic, they are just major 9ths if there's no alteration just like just 7 is not diationic, it's the minor 7th.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure I understand your question. But agreed, DEbA is an odd sound.

Comment: I think that diatonic `D` chord in minor would be `Dsus(b2)(b5)`

Comment: @MichaelCurtis You're right; my oversight. But also brings up an Interesting point. Since minor admits both flat and raised 6 and 7, I suppose you could have it both ways. I've updated my post.

Comment: That's true and complicates this question. But I figure without more context assume `iim7b5 V7 i`, a basic minor jazz progression.

Comment: You describe my problem perfectly.